# What is causing my /etc .conf file to suddenly fail on boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, configuration

I need to start some applications at boot time on 14.04 server.  I have a conf file, `/etc/init/fireimager.conf`, that executes a script that starts some other scripts, had tested it, and it worked in March.  I've been working on code and booted with the configuration file enabled today and it no longer works: it quits with an error 2.  I suspect that some update/upgrade has changed something.

I want the script to start when the boot is pretty much complete.  I'm a LINUX novice.

fireimager.conf (the log entry is not made):

```
description "Copies fireimager executeables to the ram disk and executes them."
author "Robert Lockwood"

#start on filesystem or runLevel [2345]
start on net-device-added INTERFACE=eth0
stop on shutdown

script
echo "[`date`] Fireimager initializing Started" >> /var/log/fireimager.log
exec /home/programmer/bin/init/inittest

end script
```

Comment: Try running only the script lines and see if that produces an error or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your `start` command makes your script happen too early. I don't know exactly what the fireimager does, but maybe you want to start it after networking is up?

```
start on net-device-up
```

I do not know whether the INTERFACE could be specified or not. But the net-device-added means that the interface is present, but not necessarily started which may be a problem.

You could also try your script at a command line once the system is up to make sure it works then. If so, then the `start` is certainly the only thing you need to tweak.

---

Also in the following:

```
exec /home/programmer/bin/init/inittest
```

we see that the script is placed under `/home/programmer/...` which is not considered secure. I don't think the boot scripts will detect that, but I would move that script somewhere else where the system could expect such a script (maybe under `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: You are talking about old SysV style init scripts..OP is using Upstart init and has given example of a [startup config file](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html)..

Comment: I plan to move the scripts and aps for production.  The server won't be connected to the internet then as it's used to control an airborne research grade camera.  I'll try `net-device-up`.